# Get Count from multiple table in single linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for linq query to count the records from multiple table with same id in a single query.

Table 1: Orders

| OID | VendorID | VendorName | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | Ras | 2022-09-01 | Active |
| 2 | 33 | Tek | 2022-09-02 | Processed |
| 3 | 34 | Ras | 2022-09-01 | Active |
| 4 | 45 | Yel | 2022-09-05 | Active |
| 5 | 57 | Kaw | 2022-09-07 | Processed |

Table 2: Subscribe

| SID | VendorID | SubsribePack | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | Goo | 2022-09-01 | Active |
| 2 | 34 | Yoo | 2022-09-01 | Processed |
| 3 | 35 | Too | 2022-09-04 | Active |

Table 3: Notes

| NID | VendorID | NoteDesc | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | IIT | 2022-09-01 | Active |
| 2 | 34 | NIT | 2022-09-01 | Active |
| 3 | 34 | KIT | 2022-09-01 | Active |
| 4 | 26 | LIT | 2022-09-03 | Active |
| 5 | 74 | PIT | 2022-09-04 | Processed |

I would like to count the above table records which has vendorID = 34 and Date = '2022-09-01' and Status = 'Active'.

As of now, I getting the count in each separate query

```
var OCount = Orders.Where(a=> a.VendorID = 34 && a.Date = '2022-09-01' && a.Status = 'Active').ToCount();

var SCount = Subscribe.Where(a=> a.VendorID = 34 && a.Date = '2022-09-01' && a.Status = 'Active').ToCount();

var NCount = Notes.Where(a=> a.VendorID = 34 && a.Date = '2022-09-01' && a.Status = 'Active').ToCount();
```

So that I am getting the output as,

OCount: 2
SCount: 1
NCount: 3

I am looking for a one linq query to count all the records.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to make it clear: You expect the result above to be 6 (2+1+3)?

Comment: Yes @PalleDue, I am looking for total count as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can select from the different tables the common fields and then apply the same filter:

```
int totalCount = Orders
    .Select(x => (x.VendorID, x.Date, x.Status))
    .Concat(Subscribe.Select(x => (x.VendorID, x.Date, x.Status)))
    .Concat(Notes.Select(x => (x.VendorID, x.Date, x.Status)))
    .Count(x => x.VendorID == 34 && x.Date == "2022-09-01" && x.Status == "Active");
```

If that count with condition is not supported by your version of EF, use `Where(condition).Count()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use known technique `GroupBy` by constant and then `Concat` result sets:

```cs
var OCount = Orders.Where(a => a.VendorID == 34 && a.Date == "2022-09-01" && a.Status == "Active")
    .GroupBy(x => 1).Select(g => g.Count());

var SCount = Subscribe.Where(a => a.VendorID == 34 && a.Date == "2022-09-01" && a.Status == "Active")
    .GroupBy(x => 1).Select(g => g.Count());

var NCount = Notes.Where(a => a.VendorID == 34 && a.Date == "2022-09-01" && a.Status == "Active")
    .GroupBy(x => 1).Select(g => g.Count());

var result = OCount.Concat(SCount).Concat(NCount).Sum();
```

This query will generate approximately the following SQL (if you are using EF):

```sql
SELECT SUM(s.count)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count
    FROM Orders o
    WHERE o.VendorID = 34 AND o.Date = '2022-09-01' AND o.Status = 'Active'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
    FROM Subscribe s
    WHERE s.VendorID = 34 AND s.Date = '2022-09-01' AND s.Status = 'Active'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count
    FROM Notes n
    WHERE n.VendorID = 34 AND n.Date = '2022-09-01' AND n.Status = 'Active'
) s
```

Comment: Are you sure that these queries will generate that sql? Would be great, but i doubt that the linq provider is so smart. I think the `GroupBy` will also be generated in the sql.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes I'm sure. EF Core, linq2db will generate this query.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using **same** table column types:

```
int result = Orders.Concat(Subscribe).Concat(Notes).Count(a => a.VendorID == 34 && a.Date == "2022-09-01" && a.Status == "Active");
```

With **different** types:

```
int result = Orders.Select(x => new { x.VendorID, x.Date, x.Status }).Concat(
          Subscribe.Select(x => new { x.VendorID, x.Date, x.Status })).Concat(
              Notes.Select(x => new { x.VendorID, x.Date, x.Status }))
         .Where(x => x.VendorID == 34 && x.Date == "2022-09-01" && x.Status == "Active").Count();
```

Comment: You can't union different types